# I need to display related product carousel in my sidebar

Tags: carousel, e-commerce, product, sidebar

I have added the code remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products',20); and add inside the text editor the shortcode [related_products per_page="3" columns="1"], but it is displaying unproperly. Is there is any solution

Displaying Like this:
https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-233a5a5d74.webp

Does anybody have the solution??

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At9Cq31d-6nlmjNm-oikD8-K2J9a?e=HVyfw1    :displaying like this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.